# Enabling store switcher issue in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created 2 stores, **one is english** and **one is of some other language for example italian language.**

Now, I am trying to enable store switcher, I have tried this thing:

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" before="-" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.links" />
```

in **Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**
but unfortunately it is not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **"Language switcher" (store selector)** which you can see in the top corner in the header frontend section is **Magento’s standard store view switcher (Store switcher).**

You can, for example, configure **3 store views (each with a different language)** in your Magento **and the store view switcher will appear automatically** and will work as language switcher or the store selector in the frontend of your store.